# Как обновить Centos 7.3 до Centos 7.6

Tags: linux, centos, update

Как обновиться с `Centos 7.3` до `Centos 7.6`? Нужно именно на `7.6.1810`, не новее. Пытался подключить дистрибутив `iso 7.6` и сделать его репозиторием, но обновления оттуда не подтягиваются.

Answer (score 0):

Устаревшие версии `CentOS` скачать и установить можно отсюда: http://vault.centos.org/. Далее нужно добавить (отредактировать) репозитории для основных и дополнительных пакетов.

Создаем файл `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` (редактируем существующий):

```
[base]
name=CentOS 7.6.1810 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/$basearch/
enabled=1

[updates]
name=CentOS 7.6.1810 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/updates/$basearch/
enabled=1

[extras]
name=CentOS 7.6.1810 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/extras/$basearch/
enabled=1

[centosplus]
name=CentOS 7.6.1810 - Plus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/centosplus/$basearch/
enabled=1
```

Ненужные репозитории отключаем (или можно просто удалить файлы `*.repo`):

```
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=reponame
```

Пишем в терминале:

```
$ sudo yum update
```

---

<sup>См. [«How to add a CentOS repo, having URL of Packages»](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444651/339704).</sup>